shallow routing with nextjs resets states on changing query params
I want to save a query parameter in my url on clicking a button while preserving the states of my page. When the url is "/test" and I click the button, for a split second the state is "test value" but as soon as the push operation is executed, the state resets to "initial value". When I click the button again (url is now "/test?test=10") the state is preserved and now has the value "test value".
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Test = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState('initial value');
  const { push } = useRouter();

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          push('/test/?test=10', undefined, { shallow: true });
          setState('test value');
        }}
      >
        setValue
      </button>
      <p>{state}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;

I would have expected that the states remain have the value "test value" on both click events because I use {shallow: true) in the push operation.
